# Is Vedic Vishnu the same as Puranic Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, vedas, puranas

Are there any references in the Vedas which suggest that the Vishnu, as described by the Puranas is the same as that of the Vedic?

Because in some places Vishnu is referred as one among the Adityas (sun-gods)

Comment: can you provide reference to the statement - "Because in some places Vishnu is referred as one among the Adityas (sun-gods)", would be helpful to formulate an answer. Thanks @Rakesh Joshi

Comment: The Aditya referred to as Vishnu is Vamana.

Comment: no, not the same. Iswara, Saguna Brahman, is often referred to as Brahma, Vishnu, and Siva when seen as performing either creation, preservation, or destruction in the vedas. It was only later that the personality of Vishnu alone became to be viewed as the embodiment of the Supreme Lord. Same with Siva.

Comment: @DirghaChintayanti: In Bhagavad Gita 10.21, it was mentioned by Sri Krishna that He is Vishnu among Adityas. https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?etgb=1&etssa=1&choose=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=10&field_nsutra_value=21

Comment: interesting question